Unable to Attach Access Token from acquireTokenSilent in Angular to HTTP Requests for Microsoft Graph API /v1.0/users
Creating new question as available solutions from other questions did not resolve my issue.
I am authenticating a user through Microsoft Azure AD in my Angular application. After successfully logging in, I need to fetch all user details from Microsoft AD using the API endpoint:https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
To achieve this, I acquire an access token using the acquireTokenSilent method and attempt to include it in the request's Authorization header, as shown in the following code snippet:
return from(this.msalService.acquireTokenSilent(request)).pipe(
      switchMap(tokenResponse => {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
          headers = headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${tokenResponse.accessToken}`)
        return this.http.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users', { headers : headers });
      })
    );

I am encountering a 401 Unauthorized error. After inspecting, I found that the Authorization header is missing from the request headers.
When I test the same API using Postman and cURL with the access token, it works successfully and retrieves all users from AD.
I tried to manually set the Authorization header with the token in the HTTP request, but the header still does not appear in the outgoing request. I also implemented an Angular HTTP interceptor to automatically attach the token to the Authorization header but this resulted in a circular dependency error, which I could not resolve. Also, I tried specifying the clientId in resourcemap did not help me as well. Any guidance to address this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

What is the API permission you granted to the Microsoft Entra ID application?

@Rukmini I have granted User.Read and User.Read.All permissions

Is it delegated permission?

@Rukmini yes  it is

Which account are you using? The API only supports work or school accounts (organizational accounts).. Make sure you login using work account.

@Rukmini yes I have work account. As I have already mention, I can hit api with token using postman and cURL. I am getting error only from angular as I Authorization header is not getting attached to the request. So I think problem is in the angular code

The reason behind header does not appear in the outgoing request is that msal factory functions were loading before APP_INITIALIZER. There are many solutions available for this issue. The following one helped me
Angular (v15) providers for Azure AD are executed before the APP_INITIALIZER promise is resolved
